# Deep copying (probably pointer related)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

so I'm trying to deep copy my HashTable. My hash table is an array filled with linked lists.
I've already coded the linked list constructors/copy constructors/override operators and they work perfectly.

So I've coded the following, but there's a problem in the for loop.

```
HashTable.cpp
HashTable::HashTable()
{

}
HashTable::HashTable(const HashTable & ht)
{
    bucketSize = ht.bucketSize;
    count = ht.count;
    LinkedList** table = new LinkedList*[ht.bucketSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < bucketSize; i++) {
        table[i] = new LinkedList(ht.table[i]);
    }

}

HashTable.h
class HashTable {
public:
    HashTable();
    HashTable(const HashTable& ht);
private:
    // Add your member variables and any private member functions here
    int bucketSize = defaultCapacity; //default is 101
    int count = 0;
    LinkedList table[defaultCapacity];
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with pointers, however there's no error message, only a popup when I press run: abort() has been called.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Also, you don't think it could be a problem with you having a member variable named `table`, and a ***local variable*** in the copy-constructor with the same name?

Comment: if I change that line to be:

table = new LinkedList[ht.bucketSize];

I get an error that says, table must be a modifiable lvalue.

I'm not trying to change it though. I'm trying to create a new HashTable, not modify existing ones.

Comment: That's because `table` is an array, not a pointer. And don't use arrays (or pointers) use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: In the class, you have declared `LinkedList table[defaultCapacity];` and after in the constructor you have  declared `LinkedList** table` which override the previous array.

Answer (score 0):

In the provided source code, there errors in both class and constructors declaration. To better detect those misunderstandings, it will be better to present the source code as the compiler will parse it.

**First Step** - In the `class HashTable`, all variables are only declared and not initialized.

> The `table` variable has to store an array of `LinkedList`. It is a
>   `LinkedList **table;` as declared in the copy-constructor.

```
class HashTable {
public:
    HashTable(void);
    HashTable(const HashTable& ht);
private:
    // Add your member variables and any private member functions here
    int bucketSize;
    int count;
    LinkedList **table;
};
```

**Second Step** - the default constructor `HashTable(void);` will use the `DefaultCapacity` parameter.

> In a default constructor `HashTable(void)`, a `defaultCapacity` array is created and
>   initialized with default `LinkedList()` = Empty List.

```
HashTable::HashTable(void)
{
    bucketSize = defaultCapacity; //default is 101
    count = 0;
    table = new LinkedList*[bucketSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < bucketSize; i++) {
        table[i] = new LinkedList();
    }
}
```

**Third Step** - the copy constructor `HashTable(const HashTable & ht)` create a clone array and duplicate item-LinkedList.

> In the copy constructor, each item is initialized with the
>   `LinkedList` copy constructor.
>
> **Error:** the local declaration of `LinkedList** table` override the class declaration.

```
HashTable::HashTable(const HashTable & ht)
{
    bucketSize = ht.bucketSize;
    count = ht.count;
    //LinkedList** table = new LinkedList*[ht.bucketSize];
    table = new LinkedList*[ht.bucketSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < bucketSize; i++) {
        table[i] = new LinkedList(ht.table[i]);
    }
}
```